# Android Google Analytics Experiments

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

Trying to implement Google Analytics Experiments on Android via TagManager

Analytics version : compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'

I found documentation of how to read values from it, but there are no words about support Google Experiment variable types. https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/

Code snippet :

```
        TagManager tagManager = TagManager.getInstance(LoginActivity.this);
        PendingResult<ContainerHolder> pending = tagManager.loadContainerPreferNonDefault(getString(R.string.google_tag_manager_container_id), R.raw.tag_manager_container);
        pending.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContainerHolder>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(ContainerHolder containerHolder) {
                Container container = containerHolder.getContainer();
                if (!containerHolder.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    return;
                }
                String testVariable = container.getString("LoginMethod");
            }
        }, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

All simple variable types in container are working.
But when i want to read variable type “Google Analytics Content Experiment” it’s just not working and return “invalid macro”

Does anybody knows workaround on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest version of play-services-analytics, which is 8.4.0:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'`